# How to create a number picker spinner in flluter that appers in front of screen?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

Lots of number pickers for flutter exist, like https://pub.dev/packages/numberpicker

Flutter also supports alert dialogs with the AlertDialog class: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AlertDialog-class.html

Lots of apps in native Android use number pickers that come in a kind of alert box. That is, they're not in the layout, they just appear in front of the screen and you select. Is there a way to do this in flutter?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the number picker widget inside a [SimpleDialog](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SimpleDialog-class.html). `AlertDialog` is an extension of `SimpleDialog`.